# micropost character limit error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

I am going through the ruby on rails tutorial by michael hartl.

I am running rails on windows.

The error appeared after I limited microposts to 140 characters.[image: app/models/micropost.rb]

[image: error page]

Comment: @sawa I don't see why it broke

Comment: Let me guess: because there is no method `content` in `Micropost` class? BTW, “I don't see why it broke” is still _not a question_.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have run this code:

```
$ bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Then try your app again.

---

If this doesn't fix the problem run this:

```
$ rails generate scaffold Micropost content:text user_id:integer
```

followed by:

```
$ bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Then your app should work.